# Maven inherit dependencies of dependency module

Tags: maven, module, dependencies

Currently I have a project where module B depends on module A.

Module A would be:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.A</groupId>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>A</name>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${sourceDirectory}/A/src</sourceDirectory>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Module B would be:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.A</groupId>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>B</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>B</name>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${sourceDirectory}/B/src</sourceDirectory>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.A</groupId>
      <artifactId>C</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.A</groupId>
      <artifactId>A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

In order to compile B I need the classes in a-dep. If I manually add a-dep as a dependency everything compiles fine. But the project needs me to depend on A to get to a-dep instead of explicitly declare a-dep.

Is there a way to get the classes from a-dep by depending on module A?

Comment: That should work. Can you make an example project which shows this problem...If you define a dependency you will get all transitive dependencies as well. So my question have defined a scope in the dependency?

Comment: @khmarbaise i have updated the examples with the actual code (only replaced variable names). I thought it should work too but it doesn't as when I compile B as the classes in the osgi core cause an error.

Comment: Why have defined `<sourceDirectory>${sourceDirectory}/B/src</sourceDirectory>`?

Answer (score 0):

was able to solve it by removing the true tag as it prevents B to be able to see the dependency.