# Inherit child-dependencies from maven dependency

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have two separate maven projects.
Project A contains utility classes and similar stuff. It also uses jetbrains annotations in some interfaces to mark parameters as Nullable and NotNullable.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>20.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Project B uses some of the Utilities of Project A. It includes it as a dependency from my repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.test.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>Utilities</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I can access the classes from my utilities dependency just fine. But i do not see any of the annotations on the parameters. I also can't access the jetbrains annotations in project B in any of my classes there. I'd have to add the jetbrains dependency in project B as well to do so.

Is there any way to inherit the dependencies of another dependency?
I looked at other questions and found [this similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682373/maven-inherit-dependencies-of-dependency-module). Tho his solution was to set the optional-parameter to false which i am not even using. Perhaps also something that needs to be configured in the maven build?  Currently im running my build with goals `clean package deploy` without any special additional configuration.
I know gradle builds allow for `implementation` and `api` dependencies, where one of them forwards the dependency to other projects that include it and the other doesn't.

**Edit**: Here the full configuration of my projects
Local nexus running under localhost:8081 containing my artifacts. Local TeamCity running under localhost:8080 used for the builds and deployment to the repository.

Project A pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>Utilities</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <name>Utilities</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>20.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>local_nexus</id>
            <name>Deployment</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/org.test.group/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Project B pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>TestProject</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.test.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>Utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local_nexus</id>
            <name>Deployment</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/org.test.group/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>local_nexus</id>
            <name>Deployment</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/org.test.group/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

**Edit 2:**
I've made some progress. Since i didn't change Project A's version after adding the annotations my local repository didn't fetch the new version. After a purge using `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` the updated state of version 1.0 was available.
`mvn dependency:tree` prints now

```
[INFO] org.test.TestProject:jar:1.0
[INFO] \- org.test:Utilities:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:20.1.0:compile
```

Tho my IDE (Intellij) still doesn't recognize the annotation classes inside TestProject. Any idea why this is failing now?

Answer (score 1):

You inherit `annotations` automatically, no configuration needed.

You don't inherit it, if it is of scope `provided`. Look at `mvn dependency:tree` to find out about the place and scope of the `annotations` library.

BTW: `mvn clean package deploy` is a waste of time, just use `mvn clean deploy`.

Comment: my deploy is a separate step of my build which is only executed in the very end if other steps didn't fail. but those are the only maven steps in my build. i just wrote them together so its easier to understand. Ill take a look at the scope then, thanks.

Comment: `deploy` already includes `package`, so running `package` and then `deploy` runs `package` effectively twice.

Comment: I guess a `compile` will do instead of the `package` step. `mvn dependency:tree` prints `[INFO] \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:20.1.0:compile` which i assume means its scope is `compile`, which according to documentation is `propagated to dependent projects`. Shouldn't this mean that Project B should automatically include it as well?

Comment: Have you run the `dependency:tree` on projectB?

Comment: Project B only lists the dependency for Project A, scope `compile`. `annotations` is not listed at all.

Comment: This sounds strange. I A has a compile dependency on B and  B on C, then A has also one on C. Any dependencyManagement going on? Do the versions all fit?

Comment: I've added my pom.xml of both projects and environment description to the post. As far as i can tell there is no special dependencyManagement going on. Each project is still at version 1. redeploy is enabled on nexus, so the version that is loaded from the repo is defenetly the up2date one.

Comment: I've made some progress. Read from `Edit 2` on in my post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by my local maven repository. Since i didn't change the version of Project A's artifact (always 1.0) my local repository kept providing me with the old state of version 1.0.
Using `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` i was able to cleanse the old 1.0 and load the new 1.0. Tho still my IDE refused to imports `annotations` dependency. At this point it was listed by `mvn dependency:tree` tho.
After tempering with the IDE for a while i decided to update my version to 1.1. Once Project A's 1.1 was built and Project B's dependency was updated to 1.1 it worked.

So basically it resulted from poor versioning of my projects, which interfered with my local maven repository.